# Coroutines in the app on kotlin, android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm mastering kotlin and android studio, it's time for the coroutines theme, but the code is written in the book when coroutines were an experiment and now I can't figure out how to use them, please help

Activiti

```
    package com.bignerdranch.android

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.new_character_activity.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.launch


private const val CHARACTER_DATA_KEY = "CHARACTER_DATA_KEY"



private var Bundle.characterData
    get() = getSerializable(CHARACTER_DATA_KEY) as CharacterGenerator.CharacterData
    set(value) = putSerializable(CHARACTER_DATA_KEY, value)

class NewCharacterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var characterData = CharacterGenerator.generate()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.new_character_activity)

        characterData = savedInstanceState?.characterData ?:
                CharacterGenerator.generate()

        Generate.setOnClickListener() {
            launch(UI) {
                characterData = fetchCharacterData().await()
                displayCharacterData()
            }
        }
        displayCharacterData()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.characterData = characterData
    }



    private fun displayCharacterData() {
        characterData.run {
            nameGen.text = name
            raseGen.text = rase
            dexterityNum.text = dex
            wisdomNum.text = wis
            strengthNum.text = str

        }
    }
}
```

the file where character characteristics are determined:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import java.io.Serializable
import java.net.URL

private const val CHARACTER_DATA_API = "https://chargen-api.herokuapp.com/"

private fun <T> List<T>.rand() = shuffled().first()

private fun Int.roll() = (0 until this).map {(0..6).toList().rand()}.sum().toString()

private val firstName = listOf("Eli", "Alex","Sophie")
private val lastName =  listOf("Lightweaver", "Greatfoot", "Oakenfeld")

object CharacterGenerator {
    data class CharacterData(val name: String,
                                val rase:String,
                                val dex: String,
                                val str: String,
                                val wis: String) : Serializable
    private fun name() = "${firstName.rand()} ${lastName.rand()}"
    private fun rase() =  listOf("dwarf", "elf", "human", "halfling").rand()
    private fun dex() = 4.roll()
    private fun str() = 3.roll()
    private fun wis() = 5.roll()

    fun generate() = CharacterData(name = name(),
                                    rase = rase(),
                                    dex = dex(),
                                    str = str(),
                                    wis = wis())

    fun fromApiData(apiData: String) : CharacterData {
        val (race, name, dex, wis, str) = apiData.split(',')
        return CharacterData(name,race,dex,str,wis)
    }


}
fun fetchCharacterData(): CharacterGenerator.CharacterData {
    return async {
        val apiData = URL(CHARACTER_DATA_API).readText()
        return CharacterGenerator.fromApiData(apiData)
    }
}
```

in gradle used:
module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bignerdranch.android"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'

    }
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.9"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.22.5"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Internet access is allowed in the manifest

Comment: This is a vague question. I suggest you take a look at the current coroutines documentation so you can get a better understanding of `CoroutineScope` and structured concurrency as a whole before moving forward with the details:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html#how-to-start

Comment: Can you get an updated book? Coroutines API changed very rapidly for the first two-three years. It's pretty stable now, but you'll have a very hard time learning it from an old resource, and it's complicated enough to learn as it is. I can see in just the code you've posted various completely obsolete things: `kotlin-android-extensions`, `anko`, `experimental`.